# When positioning div container white background

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, iframe

I have this picture: 
[image: http://s11.postimg.org/w230wim83/paramo_plantas_preguntas_pajonal.png]

It opens in an inline iFrame in a lightbox (I use the colorbox).
The inline iFrame contains the following:

```
<div style="display:none">
    <div id="trivia_helecho">
        <!-- HTML PART OF QUIZ-->
        <p class="question">1. What is the answer to this question?</p>        
        <ul class="answers">            
            <input type="radio" name="q1" value="a" id="q1a"><label for="q1a">Answer 1</label><br/>          
            <input type="radio" name="q1" value="b" id="q1b"><label for="q1b">Answer 2</label><br/>            
            <input type="radio" name="q1" value="c" id="q1c"><label for="q1c">Answer 3</label><br/>            
            <input type="radio" name="q1" value="d" id="q1d"><label for="q1d">Answer 4</label><br/>       
        </ul>  
    </div>        

    <div id="results">Show me the answers!</div>
</div>
```

It is a quiz which runs with an external **JS script**.
I want the **buttons + text** to position in the speach-bubble.
Doing this, I did the positioning in my external stylesheet.

```
.question {
    position: absolute;
    right: 35px;
    top: 40px;
}

.answers {
    position: absolute;
    right: 155px;
    top: 65px;
```

That's how I included the background-picture for the lightbox:

```
<style>
    #trivia_helecho {
        background-image: url("paramo_plantas_preguntas_pajonal.png");
    }
</style>
```

Just adding the position to the `.question` worked. There was no "white stuff". But moving the answers to the right added this white bars.

I removed already the `<ul> tag` for my answere class. That removed the white bars, **but** the positioning does not work anymore.

Making a `<p>` out of the `<ul>` results in white bars again.
Where do they come from?

[image: http://s10.postimg.org/t4qd8a2ax/div.png]

JAVASCRIPT ON REQUEST

That is in my HTML Document.

```
<script>
    //PRELOAD THE IMAGES
    originale = new Image(698, 233);
    originale.src = "paramo_plantas_sin_selecion.png";

    helecho = new Image(698, 233)
    helecho.src = "paramo_plantas_selecion_pajonal.png";

    //JS FUNCTION TO HIGHLIGHT THE PICTURES. IMAGEFLIP IS USED HERE
    function resaltarHelecho() {
        document.getElementById('juego_paramo').src = helecho.src;
        return true;
    }

    function originalJuego() {
        document.getElementById('juego_paramo').src = originale.src;
        return true;
    }

    //COLORBOX
    $(function(){
        $("#paramo area").colorbox({width:"698px", innerHeight:"400px", inline:true});
    });
</script>
```

That is the Quiz, making my radiobuttons interactive. Linked in the head of the **HTML** document.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#results").click(function(){
        if (!$("input[name=q1]:checked").val()){            
            alert("You're not done yet!");        
        }        

        else {            
            var cat1name = "1";            
            var cat2name = "None";
            var cat1 = ($("input[name=q1]:checked").val() != "a")
            var cat2 = (!cat1); 
            var categories = [];   
            if (cat1) { categories.push(cat1name) };            
            if (cat2) { categories.push(cat2name) };
            var catStr = 'You answered the following questions incorrectly: ' + categories.join(', ') + '';                     
            $("#categorylist").text(catStr);                        
            $("#categorylist").show("slow");
            if (cat1) { $("#category1").show("slow"); };            
            if (cat2) { $("#category2").show("slow"); };            
            { $("#closing").show("slow"); };
        }

    //TO OPEN THE RESULTS IN A NEW WINDOW
    {            
        alert(catStr);        
    } 

    });
});
```

Comment: Here is the link to without the white bars, but only the `.question` positioned http://s27.postimg.org/u1fskhmf7/div2.png

Comment: Your posted code is missing an end </div> tag btw

Comment: @proPhet thanks for the hint! Adding the `div tag` makes everything white. The background image disappears.

Comment: remember, `display:none` will make the element not display at all. Try removing this style from your containing `<div>` tag or adding `display:block`

Comment: @proPhet I need the `display:none` otherwise the `div container` will be displayed on my website, and I only want it to be displayed in the Lightbox on a clickevent.

Comment: Ok, but how is your clickevent accessing the `<div>` in question without an identifier? `<div id="container"></div>` maybe?

Comment: @proPhet that does the colorbox. I told it to open this container when clicking on a certain link.

Comment: Please post your javascript

Comment: Unless you have not included all your HTML, it looks like your javascript is targeting DOM elements that don't exist (`#categorylist, #category1, #category2 and #closing`)

Comment: @proPhet the JS works just fine :) That are thinks in the .css stylesheet. The Quiz works perfectly. The problem I am running into is that when I move the div container `trivia_helecho` I get these white squares.

Comment: are you including other css files? your answers are in a <ul> tag - there may be styles assigned to ul, li from other css files. did you check? if that's the case you'll need to overwrite those

Comment: @BirgitMartinelle Ive got this in my css `.answers li {
list-style: upper-alpha; }` but I deleted it to test weather that was what caused the problem and it did not help.